# Activiti Rest API login fails

Tags: rest, activiti

While i am logging into `activiti-rest` through this URI (`activitirest/service/login`)
`method:POST`

in body i given as

```
{
  "userId": "kermit",
  "password": "kermit"
}
```

i get the `500 internal sever error`.I am running through REST Client addon in mozilla.I also checked previous posts i tried those all still my problem is not solved.Please anyone explain how to solve this problem.In tomcat it shows the exception like this

> Exception or error caught in resource
>   org.activiti.engine.ActivitiException: Username and password does not
>   match.

Answer (score 2):

My activiti-rest war file id deployed on `tomcat server` which runs on port number `8080`. So i tried the following URL with mentioned payload, it worked for me :

`POST http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/login`

`{
  "userId": "kermit",
  "password": "kermit"
}`

When ever we hit the URL, it checks the database that is configured before deplyiong `activiti-rest` war file. You can do so by changing the `db.properties`, and the properties should be same that as `db.properties` present in `activiti-explorer`. Both should point to the same database.

The table `act_id_user` contains the user credential.

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks joshi i did already what u specified db.properties changes,but my mistake is in act_id_user table there is no data(user credential is not there)that's why i am not getting.Now my problem is solved,Thanks for u reply.

Comment: The same DB is used for both `activiti-explorer` and `activiti-rest`, as eventually it fetches data from it. So that was a right answer.